# Como enviar valores de inputs type"hidden" ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

La cuestion es la siguiente, estoy elaborando un proyecto de grado estoy realizando envio de unos valores almacenados en inputs "hidden", pero como son diferentes forms quiero intentar hacer un solo envio, el cual me envie solo los datos del form del cual se realizo la accion.

FORMS

```
<form method="post" data-toggle="GenerateTable">
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo "01";?>" data-id="tableGenID">
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo "colaborators";?>" data-role="tableGenType">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary p-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditModalCenter">
              <i class="material-icons table-icon-options">
                   edit
              </i>
          </button>
</form>

<form method="post" data-toggle="GenerateTable">
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo "01";?>" data-id="tableGenID">
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo "inventory";?>" data-role="tableGenType">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary p-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditModalCenter">
           <i class="material-icons table-icon-options">
                 edit
            </i>
       </button>
</form>
```

Envio documento php.

```
$('form[data-toggle="GenerateTable"]').submit(function(){
          $.post('../../libs/TableGenerator.php',
              {
                tableId:      $('input[data-id]').val(),
                tableType:    $('input[data-role]').val(),
              },
              function(Table_answer){
                $('#ContentTableGenerator').append(
                  $('#ContentTableGenerator').add(Table_answer.GenerateTable)
                );
              }, 'json');
              return false;
        });
```

Mi problema es que en el envio solo me toma los valores del primer Input "hidden";

Answer (score 0):

Podrias probar haciendo un arreglo y enviarlo como arreglo

```
var Arreglo=new Array();
$("input[type='hidden']").each(function(){
Arreglo.push($(this).attr("data-id"));
});
console.log(Arreglo);
```

O recorrer cada form para enviar solo los datos de ese form

Tengo entendido que solo puedes enviar un post a la vez; así que puedes intentar agrupar todo en el mismo form

Saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

Primero deberias colocarle un atributo `name` a cada input

ejmeplo:

```
<input name"nombre_campo" />
```

Segundo, coloca un `event.preventDefault()` cuando hagas el submit

```
$(...).submit( function( event ){
  event.preventDefault()
  // resto del codigo
})
```

Tercero, puedes usar un serialize y enviar el formulario de la siguiente manera

```
var datastring = $("form[data-toggle="GenerateTable"]").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "your url.php",
    data: datastring,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      // code when is success
    },
    error: function() {
      // code when have an error
    }
});
```